# Table design pattern that can support partitioning, clustered columnstore index, and spatial data?

Tags: sql-server, partitioning, spatial, columnstore

I am designing a spatial database schema for SQL Server 2016 with a table that is going to hold a large amount of rows (50+ billions, increasing by 50+ millions per day).

Requirements:

- Spatial queries must be fast
- Temporal queries (on a timestamp column) must be fast
- The table must be partitioned over the timestamp column

The schema might look something like this:

[image: Table schema]

With this schema, I can not use a clustered columnstore index due to the Position column which is a spatial type. My gut reaction to this was to split out the Position column to a new table with a 1-to-1 relationship.

[image: Table schema revised]

However, this also introduces some problems. The spatial index will not be partitioned, unless I partition the second table. To do that, I will have to duplicate the timestamp column.

Is there a better way to achieve a partitioned clustered columnstore index for this dataset?

Comment: The partitioning column must be part of the primary key (and all partitioned unique indexes) so the `BroadcastInformation` primary key will need to be implemented as a non-clustered rowstore index with both `BroadcastID` and `Timestamp`. Those columns will also need to be the  `BroadcastPosition` primary key anyway for the one-to-one relationship. I suggest you add representative queries to your question and specify if forgoing constraints in the interest of performance is an option.

Comment: Just a quick comment on this question in case someone stops by in the future; A very good stack to solve this is PostGreSQL + PostGis + Timescale. This stack is capable of outstanding performance on large amount of spatial time series data, and it's open source all the way.